# How would I reorder these deserialized XML nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I am writing a (originally) simple .xml config editor for my app.

It loads up a certain set of elements (pickable from a dropdown) from an .xml document, and lets the user edit and add to them in a DataGrid.

I figured out the loading of the xml into the dataGrid where it can be edited from a previous question I asked.

My final hurdle is that the user may want to reorder the rows in the DataGrid, and I have not found a good way to do it, without writing a lot of code that would have to be updated when a new node was to be added.

Current GUI for editing an .xml config file.

[image: Current xml config editor GUI]

Example of the .xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configurations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<FlameScanners>
    <MenuChoice>Fireye 48PT2 </MenuChoice>
    <Body>Fireye 48PT2 </Body>
    <Cost>0</Cost>
  </FlameScanners>
  <FlameScanners>
    <MenuChoice>Fireye 85 Series </MenuChoice>
    <Body>Fireye 85 Series </Body>
    <Cost>0</Cost>
  </FlameScanners>
  <FlameScanners>
    <MenuChoice>Fireye 95 Series </MenuChoice>
    <Body>Fireye 95 Series </Body>
    <Cost>0</Cost>
  </FlameScanners>
  <FlameScanners>
    <MenuChoice>-by others-</MenuChoice>
    <Body>-by others-</Body>
    <Cost>0</Cost>
  </FlameScanners>
</Configurations>
```

And a snippet of the relevant code handling all of this:

```
private Configurations deserializedXML;
public ConfigEditorWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fillSectionDropdown();
    this.deserializedXML = Deserialize<Configurations>();
}

private void comboBox_Section_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isComboBoxLoaded == false)
        return;
    switch (comboBox_Section.SelectedValue.ToString())
    {
        case "FlameScanners":
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = deserializedXML.FlameScanners;
            break;
            ...
            ...
            ...
    }
}
private static T Deserialize<T>() where T : new()
{
    // Create an instance of T
    T ReturnListOfT = CreateInstance<T>();

    // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
    using (FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream(ConfigFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        // Construct a XmlSerializer and use it  
        // to serialize the data from the stream.
        XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        try
        {
            // Deserialize the hashtable from the file
            ReturnListOfT = (T)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
    // return the Deserialized data.
    return ReturnListOfT;
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FlameScanners")]
public class FlameScanners
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MenuChoice")]
    public string MenuChoice { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Cost")]
    public string Cost { get; set; }
}
... //Repeated for each element in the config file
...
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Configurations")]
public class Configurations
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Scope")]
    public List<Scope> Scope { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Company")]
    public List<Company> Company { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ControlStrategies")]
    public List<ControlStrategies> ControlStrategies { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CustomerSpecs")]
    public List<CustomerSpecs> CustomerSpecs { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SystemSpecs")]
    public List<SystemSpecs> SystemSpecs { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ControlSystem")]
    public List<ControlSystem> ControlSystem { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CsHw")]
    public List<CsHw> CsHw { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FlameScanners")]
    public List<FlameScanners> FlameScanners { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Enclosures")]
    public List<Enclosures> Enclosures { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Options")]
    public List<Options> Options { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Documents")]
    public List<Documents> Documents { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Notes")]
    public List<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

To reiterate my question; What would be the best way to reorder a certain row in the dataGrid? I know that I have to alter the data that the dataGrid is linked to, so I thought maybe to do something like:

```
if (dataGrid.SelectedItem == null || dataGrid.SelectedIndex <= 0 || dataGrid.SelectedIndex > deserializedXML.Company.Count-1)
                return;
            Company c = deserializedXML.Company[dataGrid.SelectedIndex];
            deserializedXML.Company.RemoveAt(dataGrid.SelectedIndex);
            deserializedXML.Company.Insert(dataGrid.SelectedIndex - 1, c);
            dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

However, this would need to be in a switch statement depending on which element the user is currently viewing. Can anyone see an easier way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Use a collection view to sort, group and filter data.**

You can find a through tutorial on how to achieve this below:

[How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Would this allow me to save the XML back to the file in the new order?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging through my code, I decided the best way was to restructure how I was storing the config elements.

Instead of having a different class for each element (e.g. a Scope class, and a Company class.), I made one class that could accommodate each config element.

This way, I could have a public member of the Configurations class named CurrentlySelected. Which I would update whenever the user wanted to view a different element. 
Then if they wanted to reorder an item. I could just make changes to the CurrentlySelected member.

This saved me from having to add a lot of code every time I wanted a new config element.